# Calculate marginal totals as a function within a ddply call

Tags: r, plyr

I have been working on a file to calculate hospital infection rates. I want to standardise the infection rates to yearly procedure counts. The [**data are located here**](https://raw.github.com/johnmarquess/some.data/master/hospG.csv) because it is too big for `dput`. SSI is the number of surgical infections(1 = infected, 0=not infected), Procedure is the type of procedure. Year has been derived using `lubridate`

```
library(plyr)


fname <- "https://raw.github.com/johnmarquess/some.data/master/hospG.csv"
download.file(fname, destfile='hospG.csv', method='wget')
hospG <- read.csv('hospG.csv')

Inf_table <- ddply(hospG, "Year", summarise, 
      Infections = sum(SSI == 1),
      Procedures = length(Procedure),
      PropInf = round(Infections/Procedures * 100 ,2)
)
```

This gives me the number of infections, procedures, and proportion infected per year for this hospital.

What I would like is an additional column with the standardised proportion infected. The long way to do this outside the `inf_table` is:

```
s1 <- sum(Inf_table$Infections)
s2 <- sum(Inf_table$Procedures)

Expected_prop_inf <- Inf_table$Procedures * s1/s2
```

Is there a way to get `ddply` to do this. I tied making a function with the calculation to produce `Expected_prop_inf` but I did not get very far.

Thanks for any help offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more difficult with `ddply` because you are dividing by a number outside the grouping . Better to do it with base R.

```
# base
> with(Inf_table, Procedures*(sum(Infections)/sum(Procedures)))
[1] 17.39184 17.09623 23.00847 20.84065 24.83141 24.83141
```

rather than with `ddply` which is not so natural:

```
# NB note .(Year) is unique for every row, you might also use rownames
> s1 <- sum(Inf_table$Infections)
> s2 <- sum(Inf_table$Procedures)
> ddply(Inf_table, .(Year), summarise, Procedures*(s1/s2))
  Year      ..1
1 2001 17.39184
2 2002 17.09623
3 2003 23.00847
4 2004 20.84065
5 2005 24.83141
6 2006 24.83141
```

Comment: I think you'd just do `Inf_table <- mutate(Inf_table, Expected_prop_inf = Procedures * sum(Infections) / sum(Procedures))`

Comment: @hadley - mutate is exactly what I needed. It prompted me to go back to the docs and work through the functionality from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to aggregate using `data.table`.
I'm not sure if it's posible to do it in one step.

```
require("data.table")

fname <- "https://raw.github.com/johnmarquess/some_data/master/hospG.csv"
hospG <- read.csv(fname)

Inf_table <- DT[, {Infections = sum(SSI == 1)
                   Procedures = length(Procedure)
                   PropInf = round(Infections/Procedures * 100 ,2)
                   list(
                     Infections = Infections,
                     Procedures = Procedures,
                     PropInf = PropInf
                   )
                   }, by = Year]


Inf_table[,Expected_prop_inf := list(Procedures * sum(Infections)/sum(Procedures))]

tables()
```

The added bonus of this approach is that you are not creating another data.table in the second step, a new column of the data.table is created. This would be relevant in case your datasets are bigger.